# Alternative way/application of Affine Transformations?

Tags: matlab, matrix, affinetransform

Complicated question here, but I'll try to explain phrase it clearly;

## Situation

I've got a code where (covariance) matrix A is transformed by adding a (generated/given) matrix B, followed by dividing it with a certain value:

`A_new = (A_old + B) / constant`

This transformation includes *scaling* & *rotation*, no *translation*.
This is a different way of transforming a matrix than I am used to ([which is like this](https://nl.mathworks.com/discovery/affine-transformation.html))

## What I want

I want to decompose/reassemble matrix B in such a way that it performs a *rotation* to matrix A, but **doesn't** *scale* matrix A (eigenvectors same length)

In regular affine transformations it would involve [something like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237369/given-this-transformation-matrix-how-do-i-decompose-it-into-translation-rotati), but this is not really applicable due to the alternative method to transform a matrix (as described above).

## Solution, the hard way

One thing I could do is:

1. Determine the orientation of the eigenvectors in matrix A_new and matrix A_old
2. Calculate the difference in orientation
3. Create rotation matrix R
4. Calculate `A_new = A_old*R`

But isn't there an easier way? Any advice (or keywords) that can help me solve get *only* a rotation by adjusting matrix B in `A_new = (A_old + B) / constant`?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Added code:

```
    for k=1:m0.nbStates
        %Update the centers
        Mu(:,k) = (Mu0(:,k).*Ek0(k) + NewData*Pix(:,k)) / (Ek0(k)+Ek(k));
        
        %Update the covariance matrices
        S1 = zeros(m0.nbVar,m0.nbVar);
        for j=1:nbData
            dx = NewData(:,j)-Mu(:,k);
            S1 = S1 + (dx)*(dx)'.*Pix(j,k);
        end
        dx0 = Mu0(:,k)-Mu(:,k);
        S2 = (Sigma0(:,:,k)+(dx0)*(dx0)').*Ek0(k);
        Sigma(:,:,k) = (S1 + S2) / (Ek0(k)+Ek(k));
    end
```

The method above is the Gaussian Mixture Model Direct Update method. It updates Gaussian distributions when new data is available. For my research I want to adjust the (2D) orientation of the Gaussians rather than their size.

Second way to alter a Gaussian Mixture model is as follows;

```
% Implementation of incremental learning algorithm, as described by
% Rafael Pinto and Paulo Engel in their paper:
% "Scalable and Incremental Learning of Gaussian Mixture Models" (2017)

v1   = v0+1;         %Eq 4.
sp1  = sp0+P_jx;     %Eq 5.
e_j  = X - Mu0;      %Eq 6.
w_j  = P_jx / (sp1+realmin);   %Eq 7.
dMu  = w_j*e_j;      %Eq 8.
Mu1  = Mu0 + dMu;    %Eq 9.
e_j  = X - Mu1;      %Eq10.

Sigma1 = (1-w_j)*Sigma0+w_j*(e_j*e_j')-dMu*dMu';
```

This method also adjusts the Covariance matrix 'Sigma0' to 'Sigma1' by adding a second term.

Comment: How can `B` rotate `A` when it is being added (as opposed to multiplied)?

Comment: You'll have to explain how addition can rotate. The only way I see this is possible is to construct `B=A_old*R-A_old`, but that defeats the purpose I think.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I will add the MatLab code and try to explain more. @CrisLuengo, I'm indeed not looking to calculate B (since it is given), but I want to adjust B in such a way that it only has rotational effects on A.